# How to compare table columns and match them in SQL Sever 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2012

This is a bit of a HW assignment at work.

What I'm doing at work right now is database archiving. I take a source DB and move all (or specific portion) of data into a new archive DB using a stored procedure.

Problem is, not all of the columns in the source DB match the destination DB.

How can I compare the tables in the DBs for missing columns and then match them? So if source DB has Table 1 that has 4 columns and destination DB has Table 1 that only has 2 columns, how can I compare both Table 1's and then have it add/delete columns to match each other?

SQL Server 2012/SQL Management Studio

Comment: You can run queries on `sys.columns` or `Information_schema.Columns` to get the columns in any table.

Answer (score 0):

You can compare the table Columns by querying Information_Schema.Columns or sys.Columns.

The below query will provide number of missing columns

```
SELECT c2.table_name,c2.COLUMN_NAME
FROM archdb.[INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[COLUMNS] c2
WHERE table_name='archtable' and c2.COLUMN_NAME 
    not in (SELECT column_name 
    FROM orgdb.[INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[COLUMNS] 
    WHERE table_name='orgtable')
```

This [link](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2779/ways-to-compare-and-find-differences-for-sql-server-tables-and-data/) will provide information about number of ways and tools available to compare sql server tables